# ¿Que significan los "this" y los "prototype" en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

antes de nada anticipar que mi prgunta no es de JavaScript, sino de Processing.js.
Estoy tomando clases de programación y a veces nos obligan a utilizar cosas que no han explicado y simplemente no entendemos. En este caso tengo este fragmente de código.

```
    var Beaver = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Happy");
    this.sticks = 0;
};

Beaver.prototype.draw = function() {
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};
```

Me gustaría que alguien me explicase que implicas esos "this" y esos .prototype que hay en el código, por favor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Javascript es un lenguaje orientado a Prototipos (**Prototypes**), que es un estilo de programación orientada a objetos en el cual, las clases no están presentes, y la re-utilización de procesos (que es como decir la herencia en otros lenguajes) se obtiene a través de la clonación de objetos ya existentes.

Por otro lado, la palabra reservada **this** hace referencia al objeto mismo, en este caso al prototipo.

Yo te recomiendo que estudies programación orientada a objetos, con Python, para que luego puedas entender un poco mejor cómo funcionan los prototipos, porque funcionan similares.

Comment: No veo recomendable Python para entender los prototype de JS pues son concepciones diferentes

Comment: @element más o menos para que le vaya cogiendo el aire a como se usa "Javascript orientado a objetos"; de hecho puede usar TypeScript que es muy necesario para Angular por ejemplo. Es solamente una opinión.

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es para dar opiniones, por el contrario se trata de resolver la duda expuesta, aquí nada tiene que hacer ni angular y menos TS

Comment: Gra ias por la contribución Diesan, Con respecto a realizar respuestas en el sitio es muy importante revises [answer], se pregunta acerca de javascript y es recomendable realizar la respuesta orientada a la tecnología definida en la pregunta, saludos.